# How to design a cable pull relief?

Tags: pla, 3d-design

A thick power cable will go into my 3D-printed device, and I am looking for options to design a "pull relief" against the full pull power of a human.
Ideally, it should be designed mostly on a flat surface and heat-resistant.

For example, forming a U-loop from the cable and applying a zip tie provides perfect pull relief that I am unable to break with my hands.
However, I am struggling to translate that knowledge into some 3D-print-friendly design.

I've been thinking about creating a clamp of sorts consisting of two plastic elements, where the second one is pushed into the cable using a screw from the outside - am I going in a good direction?

Can you suggest a working design for such pull relief without the zip tie?

Some ideas for inspiration:

- [Power Cord/Cable Strain Relief](https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/tool/power-cord-cable-strain-relief)
- [Strain relief clip 3D for print](https://www.3dforprint.com/3dmodel/strain-relief-clip/5452)
- [Hillman 58236 0.375 Diameter Round Strain Relief Bushing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MFSEYGG)

Comment: Welcome. It would be helpful to provide a sketch, drawing or model for what you're trying to achieve and ask a specific question about what you're trying to learn. I suggest reflecting that question in the title by editing your post.

Comment: This sounds more like a UI question than a "how can I get this to print successfully". Perhaps more detail as to how it relates to the 3D printing aspect could help.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I can think of. The Z channel is where you lay your cable inside. Maybe this is something similar to your "U-loop"? This works by transforming the pulling force into the friction between the cable and the internal walls of the channel: The harder you pull, the bigger the friction it generates, thus keeping it in place. This can be totally 3d-printed flatly and the strength of this would depend on your 3d-printing material, thickness, which I think is enough for your goal.

Now, you need to think about the cons of this design:

1. Space consuming
2. Overbending your cable, damaging it
3. You need to know your cable size before implementing this design, as it requires a tight fit. This means you have to change the design if you want to use a thicker or thinner wire in the future in development

Hope it helps, feel free to point out other flaws of this design.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to "design a thing that must accomodate a thing" is to first model the thing you need accomodated, add technical margins, then boolean subtract it from a solid block. Then carve the rest of the block to a neater shape, removing unnecessary material, making screw holes and so on.

So, first make the U loop on the cable, with the zip ties, as you found working. Use vernier calipers to measure the real-world model then re-create it in CAD. Make it thicker by some 10-20% than your measurements. Then create a separate object - something very roughly the shape of the strain relief, without any cable channels, then use Boolean operation to subtract the cable from it. Add any stubs to keep the cable from escaping, mounts to keep the cable relief attached to whatever you need to attach it to, extra supports for strength where you suspect it could break, then print it. Try to fit the cable, chance it will work the first time over are slim, but you'll find where adjustments need to be made, and repeat the process until you have a working product.